# Ventilation fan (blower fan) stopped working

Tags: opel, fan, corsa, heater-blower

I have a problem in My Car (Opel Corsa-c 2006), The Ventilation fan (Blower fan) stopped working, What was happen the fan was working fine, I turned on the car while the fan was on the last speed, it works fine and stopped after 2 seconds
I checked the fuse box, there is no problem found
Thanks and sorry for my English
please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blower motor should have two wires, one is a ground fed by a mechanical or solid state resister/HVAC computer. The other is fused power, this may or may not have a relay.

Check for power on one wire and variable ground on the other.

If you're missing power check your fuses again you may have missed one. If it has a relay try swapping it with another relay in the fuse block. If the fuses are OK you're going to have to inspect the wiring harness from the blower motor to whichever fuse block it pulls power from.

If you're missing ground, the resister is usually the first place to look. You may have to find wiring diagrams for this part, but it should be pretty straight forward. The switch or control unit supplies ground to the resister and then from the resister to the blower motor.

If you have both power and ground at the blower motor connector replace the blower motor.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to call local auto parts to see if they sell a resistor block for your vehicle. Many cars will run on high speed only with a blown resistor block for the fan speed control...